# Amazon Athena get data from the past one hour

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have some data rows in AWS Athena table and I am trying to get the data from the last 1 hour. I am using awswrangler, I will post my snippet below. Basically, instead of querying all data and then filtering out only the last 1 hour with Python, I would like to do that in the Athena SQL query so that I get a faster response (and thus execution time of the program). My code is:

```
import awswrangler as wr
import boto3

session=boto3.Session()
df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(f"""SELECT *
                                  FROM data_table""",
                                  database="database",
                                  keep_files = False,
                                  boto3_session = session).sort_values('timestamp')
```

My progress:
I can get the current timestamp with `"SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"` , but this will return the timestamp in a date format. In order to get the last 1 hour, my idea is to convert 1 hour to milliseconds as well, and subtract it from the milliseconds of current timestamp and apply it as a filter.

NOTE! `timestamp` in the table is in milliseconds.

Comment: Another idea: use awswrangler.s3.list_objects and give it a last_modified_begin param. But this will require me to combine dataframes and so on. In a perfect case, I would just use the athena query solve my need. But this is also a workaround

Comment: Can you share some sample data of timestamp.  Is that just the time or is it sometime more like epoch time?

Comment: Yes, sure. This is an example timestamp: 1650578683860

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option would be to convert the timestamp and then filter with subtracting an hour from the current time.

Assuming the value in timestamp is milliseconds since epoch you can use [from_unixtime](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_unixtime):

Based on your sample value provided to see how that works:

```
select from_unixtime(1650578683860/1000e0)
```

Which then gives the result:

```
2022-04-21 22:04:43.860
```

Then you can use DATE_ADD and subtract an hour from CURRENT_STAMP, so the where clause would be something like:

```
WHERE from_unixtime("timestamp"/1000e0) >= DATE_ADD('hour', -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: That seems to work perfectly! I don't know why there is no such question around stack overflow. Thank you so much.